# I dont see the error but the message "illegal character in ar." popped up (line 14)

Tags: math-mode, arrays

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\oddsidemargin=0pt
\topmargin=0pt
\textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=8.5in
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\large\bf\LaTeX\ Example 7}
\end{center}
This example demostrates two methods for typesetting piecewise defined functions.
The array structure can be used to typeset function definitions that have multiple cases:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{r@{\quad\mathrm{if}\quad} i}
x^2-1 & x\in(-infty,-1]\vspace{2pt}\\
{\displaystyle \frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}} & x\in(-1,1)
\vspace{6pt}\\
x^2+1 & x\in, \infnty) \vspace{4pt}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no `i` column type. Use either `l`, `r` or `c`... Also, there is no macro `\infnty`; you probably mean to use `\infty`, and avoid adding `\vspace`s in your `array` - use the optional argument to ``\\`` for that. Finally, see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Comment: Yes, I did make the mistake of using \infnty instead of \infty. Thanks! My professor wants us to use \vspace so idk if he will ok with the optional argument but do you know of any other column type for I? ive tried all three you suggested and it still wont compile

Comment: It compiles fine if you use `r@{\quad\mathrm{if}\quad} l`...

Comment: I'm sorry I was doing something wrong on my end. Your advice really helped.  Thanks so much!